# How to divide data programmatically in a data table in R

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I have a code as given below:

```
newdata <- ddply(data, .(SIC,FYEAR), function(x){if(nrow(x)>7) x else NULL});
```

In this code the function is applied on each fragment of data being divided by `SIC`, and `FYEAR`. How can I write a generic function which allows for creation of fragments programmatically in data tables? Something like,

```
newdata <- ddply(data, .(col1,col2,...,coln), function(x){if(nrow(x)>7) x else NULL});
```

but an equivalent solution in data tables, where both n and the names of columns are given programmatically. It would be more helpful if someone can let me know a solution based on data tables. Thanks.

A reproducible example goes below:

```
require(data.table)
data <- data.table(structure(list(SIC = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), FYEAR = c(1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012), BIG4 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), .Names = c("SIC", "FYEAR", "BIG4"
), row.names = c(31842L, 48128L, 982L, 2173L, 8655L, 31843L, 
55799L, 62384L, 983L, 2174L, 7034L, 8656L, 36790L, 51631L, 69782L, 
31844L, 55800L, 62385L, 984L, 7035L, 8657L, 18874L, 36791L, 51632L, 
69783L, 985L, 7036L, 8658L, 13375L, 18875L, 31845L, 36792L, 51633L, 
62386L, 69784L, 986L, 2177L, 7037L, 8659L, 18876L, 36793L, 51634L, 
55801L, 62387L, 69785L, 36794L, 987L, 2178L, 7038L, 8660L, 18877L, 
51635L, 62388L, 7039L, 36795L, 988L, 2179L, 8661L, 18878L, 62389L, 
19823L, 36796L, 989L, 2180L, 8662L, 18879L, 62390L, 19824L, 36797L, 
2181L, 8663L, 18880L, 19825L, 36798L, 2182L, 8664L, 69790L, 24268L, 
24325L, 36799L, 2183L, 8665L, 31852L, 24269L, 29392L, 36800L, 
2184L, 8666L, 18883L, 31853L, 69792L, 24270L, 36801L, 2185L, 
8667L, 18884L, 26989L, 31854L, 69793L, 30612L), class = "data.frame"))
```

## Edit:

Let say I want to write a function, and pass `cols = c("BIG4")` or `cols = c("SIC", "FYEAR")` etc. to define the columns which is used to fragment the data and then delete those fragments having less than 8 data points and then combine the left fragments and then return the joined dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two approaches.

```
# using .SD
foo.SD <- function(x, .by,.thresh){
        x[,if(.N>.thresh){.SD},by=.by]
      }
# using .I (should be slightly faster as .SD is not loaded into memory for
# each group
foo.I <- function(x, .by,.thresh){
       x[x[,if(.N>.thresh){.I},by=.by]$V1]
 }

foo.SD(data, c('SIC','FYEAR'), 7)
foo.I(data, c('SIC','FYEAR'), 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the `nrow` condition in the `j` argument of `[.data.table`, the trick is to return an empty version of the same `data.table` for groups which do not pass the required number of rows, using `data[0]`:

```
# Discard chunks of a data.table which have less than a specified number of rows
throwAwaySmall <- function(data, cols, rowSizeThreshold) {
  data[, .SD[.N>rowSizeThreshold], by=cols]
}
```

The following is now equivalent to your first piece of code:

```
throwAwaySmall(data, c("SIC", "FYEAR"), 7)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want a similar solution for a data table.

Comment: @Sumit I've now changed it to a proper `data.table` solution

Comment: Or more concisely, `data[, .SD[.N>rowSizeThreshold], by=cols]`

Comment: @ScottRitchie The table returned by your code only has three columns - SIC, FYEAR, and the number of rows in a given fragmented data. It completely ignores other data columns and doesn't return them in the output table.

Comment: @Sumit weird... `.SD` should return all the columns.  I've modified it to be Shadow's answer.

Comment: Note that this will be inefficient as it calls `[.data.table` for each  by grouping. Lots of groups = lots of unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
DT<-data.table(df,key=c("SIC","FYEAR"))
DT[,list(BIG4,incl=length(BIG4)>7),by=c("SIC","FYEAR")][incl==T]
```

Comment: I think my question is not clear enough. I want to fragment the data using a generic code, which means instead of .(SIC,FYEAR), I can have .(BIG4) or .(SIC,BIG4) or ...I hope you get the idea.